# API Controller : Cannot PUT, Cannot DELETE (404 not found)

Tags: node.js, rest, express, postman, nestjs

With Nest.js, and a basic controller :

```
import { Body, Controller, Delete, Get, Param, Post, Put, Query } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Hero } from '../entities/hero.entity';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@Controller('hero')
export class HeroController {
  constructor(private readonly heroesService: HeroService) {}

  @Get()
  async get(@Query() query): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return await this.heroesService.find(query);
  }

  @Get(':id')
  async getById(@Param('id') id): Promise<Hero> {
    return await this.heroesService.findById(id);
  }

  @Post()
  async add(@Body() hero: Hero): Promise<Hero> {
    return await this.heroesService.save(hero);
  }

  //TODO: doesn't seem to work, never called (request 404)
  @Put(':id')
  async update(@Param('id') id, @Body() hero): Promise<Hero> {
    console.log('hey');
    return await this.heroesService.update(id, hero);
  }

  //TODO: doesn't seem to work, never called (request 404)
  @Delete('/delete/:id')
  async remove(@Param('id') id): Promise<Hero> {
    console.log('hey');
    return await this.heroesService.remove(id);
  }
}
```

Following the basic documentation of nest.js, a module with a controller and a service, injecting a typeorm repository for the entity 'Hero'.

Using Postman, both @Get, @Get(':id') and @Post work perfectly, my entity->repository->service->controller connects to my local Postgres DB, and I can get/add/update data from the Hero table with those API endpoints.

However, PUT and DELETE requests respond with :

```
{
    "statusCode": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "Cannot PUT /hero"
}

X-Powered-By →Express
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length →67
ETag →W/"43-6vi9yb61CRVGqX01+Xyko0QuUAs"
Date →Sun, 02 Dec 2018 11:40:41 GMT
Connection →keep-alive
```

The request for this is localhost:3000/hero (same endpoint as GET and POST), i've tried either by adding a id:1 in Params or in the Body with x-www-form-urlencoded.

The requests don't ever seem to arrive at the controller (nothing called), i've added a globalinterceptor to Nest.js that just does this :

```
intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    call$: Observable<any>,
  ): Observable<any> {
    console.log(context.switchToHttp().getRequest());
    return call$;
  }
```

But again it only logs GET and POST requests, the others never appear.

What confuses me is that I've pretty much followed the Nest.js doc, made a basic controller and service, entity/repository connected to DB, there doesn't seem to be anything else needed for this to work, and yet PUT and DELETE appear to not exist.

Comment: Judging from msg `Cannot PUT /hero` you are making a `/hero` request rather than for example `/hero/1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from msg Cannot PUT /hero you are making a /hero request rather than for example /hero/1

> The request for this is localhost:3000/hero (same endpoint as GET and POST), i've tried either by adding a id:1 in Params or in the Body with x-www-form-urlencoded.

The PUT request should be done with `localhost:3000/hero/<id_here>` Think you are confusing query params with path params.

Simmilarly DELETE should be done on `localhost:3000/hero/delete/<id_here>`

Comment: Wow do I feel silly. I got confused by Postman and thought the ID for a put/delete had to be a param.